# Lodash Functions giving "TypeError: _.lowerCase is not a function" error

Tags: node.js, lodash

```
var _= require('lodash');

var _= require('lodash/core');

var fp = require('lodash/fp');


var array = require('lodash/array');
app.get('/home/:Titleid', function (req, res) {
  let TitleId=_.lowerCase(req.params.Titleid);
})
```

I have installed Lodash package properly, but when i try to use any function  it gives error

Comment: It's basically a typo. You're overwriting `_` with `require("lodash/core")`. `lodash/core` doesn't have `lowerCase`. Just remove that import, since you've already imported `lodash` as `_` (and `lodash` *does* have `lowerCase`). (Side note: Use `let` or `const`, so that duplicate declarations are the errors they always should have been.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the `lodash` import (`_`) with `var _= require('lodash/core');`. Remove that line and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
const _ = require('lodash');
```

This will load the full build and in my case, only this line was required.